# UnboundLocalError - local variable 'ret' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-models, methods, django-rest-framework

I did a simple method to calculate the division between two values:

```
def porc_pago_ct(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for contrato in self.contrato.all():
        if contrato.nr_contrato != None:
            ret = (float(contrato.total_pago_brl)/float(self.valor_total_brl))*100
        else:
            ret = 0
    return ret
```

Everything works well until I put this conditional statements. After this I tried many ways, but everytime I got:

> UnboundLocalError at /lista/2/
>
> local variable 'ret' referenced before assignment

What I`m missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Is self.contrato.all() an empty queryset?  If it is, you never enter the loop and never set the "ret" variable.